# EMBEDDED C - Volatile qualifier does not matter in my interrupt routine

Tags: c, embedded, volatile

I am new to embedded C, and I recently watched some videos about volatile qualifier. They all mention about the same things. The scenarios for the use of a volatile qualifier :

1. when reading or writing a variable in ISR (interrupt service routine)
2. RTOS application or multi thread (which is not my case)
3. memory mapped IO (which is also not my case)

My question is that my code does not stuck in the `whiletest();`function below
when my UART receives data and then triggers the `void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)` interrupt function

```
int test;

int main(void)
{
  test = 0;
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t *)&ch, 1);

  while (1)
   {
        Delay(500);     
        printf("the main is runing\r\n");
        whiletest();
   }
}

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if(huart->Instance == USART1)
    {
        test = 1;
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t *)&ch, 1);
    }
}

void whiletest(void)
{
int count =0;
while(!test){
 count++;
 printf("%d\r\n",count);
 Delay(2000);
 }
}
```

I use keil IDE and stm32cubeIDE. I learned that the compiler would optimize some instructions away if you choose the o2 or o3 optimization level. Therefore, I chose the o2 level for build option, but it seems no effect on my code. The compiler does not optimize the load instruction away in the while loop and cache the test value `0` in the main function as the videos teach on youtube. It is confusing. In what situation I am supposed to use volatile qualifier while keep my code optimized (o2 or o3 level).

note: I am using stm32h743zi (M7)

Comment: `Test` is not the same thing as `test`.  So, is there more code here you're not showing?

Comment: Not all resources are of equal quality.  I note in particular that in C and C++, `volatile` has no valid use specific to multithreaded programs, contrary to what some of the resources you examined seem to have told you.  That's a somewhat common misconception.

Comment: As for "*The compiler does not optimize the load instruction away*", you would be well advised to write C code for which the C language defines the needed semantics, instead of relying on the compiler performing or avoiding specific optimizations, except to the extent that the language speaks to what kinds of optimizations can be performed (which is where `volatile` comes in).  Where you need opcode-level control over the binary, you should be writing in assembly.

Comment: Please don't tag irrelevant languages.

Comment: You won the compiler lottery -- your compiler is more interested in being useful than scoring well on an artificial benchmark.   Sadly, you shouldn't rely on this, as it may change with updates or build options.

Comment: The volatile keyword only prevents optimisation.  Lack of volatile does not _cause_ optimisation.  Without it, the code is unsafe in the sense that the behaviour could change with a different compiler, different switches, of following some code change.  Here as stated by @doron, the _compiler_ cannot know if test is not modified externally.  A different toolchain with link time optimisation may change that.  Make test static will also change that.

Comment: If you declare `static int test;` guaranteeing then that `test` is not externally referenced, YMMV. But ultimately the optimiser is not required to behave in any particular manner, it is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler may only optimize (change) code if the optimized code behaves as if it the optimizer did nothing.

In your case you are calling two functions (Delay and printf) in your while loop.  The compiler has no visibility of what these functions do since they appear in a separate compiler unit. The compiler therefore must assume they may change the value of the global variable test and therefore cannot optimize out the check for the value in test. Remove the function calls and the compiler may well optimize out the check for value of test.

Comment: Declaring `static int test;` will also localise the shared variable and allow the optimisation.

Comment: My way of trying to figure out the problem could be the culprit here ! Thank you for providing the insightful answer. I will look up the assembly code with delay() and printf() deleted.

Answer (score 4):

`volatile` informs the compiler that object is side effects prone. It means that it can be changed by something which is not in the program execution path.

As you never call the interrupt routine directly compiler assumes that the `test` variable will never be `1`. You need to tell him (`volatile` does it) that it may change anyway.

example:

```
volatile int test;

void interruptHandler(void)
{
    test = 1;
}

void foo(void)
{
    while(!test);
    LED_On();
}
```

Compiler knows that the `test` can be changed somehow and **always** read it in the `while` loop

```
foo:
        push    {r4, lr}
        ldr     r2, .L10
.L6:
        ldr     r3, [r2]     //compiler reads the value of the test from the memory as it knows that it can change.
        cmp     r3, #0
        beq     .L6
        bl      LED_On
        pop     {r4, lr}
        bx      lr
.L10:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
test:
```

Without the `volatile` compiler will assume that the `test` always will be zero.

```
foo:
        ldr     r3, .L10
        ldr     r3, [r3]
        cmp     r3, #0
        bne     .L6
.L7:
        b       .L7     //dead loop here
.L6: 
        push    {r4, lr}
        bl      LED_On
        pop     {r4, lr}
        bx      lr
.L10:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
test:
```

In your code you **have to** use volatile if the object is changed by something which is not in the program path.

Comment: May i add to use a bool for these flag type variables.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question, which says that the while loop _does_ exit